# How do I set arguments via the Python script for Youtube API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I upload a video from python using youtube data api, I use this code from the sample:

```
    argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Video file to upload")
argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Video description",
                       default="Test Description")
argparser.add_argument("--category", default="22",
                       help="Numeric video category. " +
                       "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list")
argparser.add_argument("--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated",
                       default="")
argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus", choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
                       default=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0], help="Video privacy status.")
args = argparser.parse_args()
```

This means that i have to set all the arguments, such as --file, --title, --description etc directly from the command line. I want to set them from the script. How do I do this?

Edit: solved, make required=False

Comment: When you say set them from the script, does that mean use default values if ones are not provided?

Comment: well if that would work then I guess, but I don't think you can set a default video path?

Comment: you get this error even if you try and add a default parameter to --file error: the following arguments are required: --file

Comment: That's because you've set `required=True`

Comment: Genius! Thanks so much ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the --file argument as required with `required=True` so if you set that to false you should not get the error!

Good luck!